# Create JsonArray with adding JSonObject

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I have a JSONObject like below I got it uses this code,I have many jsonString and I want to append it each other and create JSONArrray, how can I do this?

```
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String

{
 "accuracy":50,"lat":40.988117004782879,
 "speed":0,
 "lon":29.097426245016134,
 "satellite":6,
 "airplaneMode":false
},
{
 "accuracy":50,"lat":40.988117004782879,
 "speed":0,
 "lon":29.097426245016134,
 "satellite":6,
 "airplaneMode":false
},
{
 "accuracy":50,"lat":40.988117004782879,
 "speed":0,
 "lon":29.097426245016134,
 "satellite":6,
 "airplaneMode":false
}
```

how can I add these JSONArray format like below

```
[
{
"accuracy":50,
"lat":40.988117004782879,
"speed":0,
"lon":29.097426245016134,
"satellite":6,
"airplaneMode":false
},
{
"accuracy":50,
"lat":40.988117004782879,
"speed":0,
"lon":29.097426245016134,
"satellite":6,
"airplaneMode":false
},
{
"accuracy":50,
"lat":40.988117004782879,
"speed":0,
"lon":29.097426245016134,
"satellite":6,
"airplaneMode":false
}
]
```

Comment: Please, this is Swift, the *objective-c-ish* syntax `NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String` is horrible. Declare `jsonData` as `Data` (unlike `NSData`) and write `String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: What are JSONObject and JSONArray, sounds like Java class names to me? You need to clarify what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create use **`Codable`** to parse the above `data`.

If the JSON format is like,

```
[
  {
    "accuracy": 50,
    "lat": 40.98811700478288,
    "speed": 0,
    "lon": 29.097426245016134,
    "satellite": 6,
    "airplaneMode": false
  },
  {
    "accuracy": 50,
    "lat": 40.98811700478288,
    "speed": 0,
    "lon": 29.097426245016134,
    "satellite": 6,
    "airplaneMode": false
  },
  {
    "accuracy": 50,
    "lat": 40.98811700478288,
    "speed": 0,
    "lon": 29.097426245016134,
    "satellite": 6,
    "airplaneMode": false
  }
]
```

**Model:**

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let accuracy: Int
    let speed: Int
    let lat: Double
    let lon: Double
    let satellite: Int
    let airplaneMode: Bool

}
```

**Parsing:**

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([Response].self, from: data)
        print(response)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to parse Data,I want to Create JSONArray with JSONObjects